# How get deleted (deleted_at) fields with mongoid?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I can get some data with `where()` method, but if some records were deleted with Paranoia `delete()` method (the `deleted_at` field is set with the date of deletion) they are not returned in the results.

I can get those records using `collection.deleted.entries.find()` with Moped, but I need it as usual Mongoid criteria data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paranoia plugin sets a default_scope on the model.

```
included do
  field :deleted_at, type: Time
  class_attribute :paranoid
  self.paranoid = true

  default_scope where(deleted_at: nil)
  scope :deleted, ne(deleted_at: nil)
  define_model_callbacks :restore
end
```

You can tell Mongoid not to apply the default scope by using `unscoped`, which can be inline or take a block.

```
Band.unscoped.where(name: "Depeche Mode")
Band.unscoped do
  Band.where(name: "Depeche Mode")
end
```